# Replicate mysqldump functionality using only queries

Tags: php, mysql, dump

How do I backup a MySQL database using just queries?
I mean, PHP's `system()` function is disables for security reasons, thus I cannot invoke `mysqldump`.

For table structure I use this:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name
```

But how about table data? Does a predefined SQL command exist? I tried with `SELECT ... INTO var_list`, but I cannot get this to work (`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` is not suitable for me, as the db host is different from the server I have access to).

Thanks for your help, and sorry for being such a noob, but this is my first question here! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty straightforward to create `INSERT` statements in your PHP code from a `SELECT * FROM table` query. Here's an example:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=DATABASE;host=HOST', 'USER', 'PASSWORD');
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');

$columns = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $result->columnCount(); $i++) {
  $column = $result->getColumnMeta($i);
  $columns[] = sprintf('`%s`', $column['name']);
}
$colstring = implode(',', $columns);

$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$inserts = array();
foreach($rows as $r) {
  $values = array_map(function($e) use ($db) {
      return $db->quote($e);
    },
    $r);
  $valstring = implode(',', $values);
  $inserts[] = sprintf('INSERT INTO table (%s) VALUES (%s)',
                       $colstring,
                       $valstring);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't wanna have PHP making backups of your database. Only the database (management software) itself can backup a database properly, there's no good reason why you'd wanna do it on your own.

You'll be facing huge issues if you're gonna do this with PHP or with separate queries or with a combination of both.

Comment: I know which the risks are. It's the backup of a script I wrote, so I should know how tables are structured.
Anyway, this is mainly a try. Thanks for your answer, but this will not prevent me from trying anyway! :)